# How to get YUV video data stream from web cameras in C# NOT USING DIRECT SHOW?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, webcam, yuv

What I need is raw camera data Stream of images\Frames in YUV format. I need to get tham using C#. And NOT USING DIRECT SHOW (if possible at all). I need a live stream not something like 1 frame per 5 seconds. If It will be mono compateble it would be grate but win only will be ok. I use .Net 3.5 but if needed I can swich to 4.

I heard Silverlight 4 can grab YUV stream so how to do it from ragular C# programm?

So How to get YUV video data stream from web cameras in C# NOT USING DIRECT SHOW?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing but am having little luck.  Your post here on SO is the first promising thing I've seen so far... and there aren't even any replies :)

Comment: were u able to solve this, i need help too

Answer (score 1):

getting raw yuv data frome webcam without DirectShow might be impossible as far as I know. 
Opencv VideoCapture class use DirectShow as well.

For DirectShow solutions: check [here](http://www.infognition.com/blog/2013/working_with_raw_video_in_c_sharp_directshow.html)

I have a simpler solution(based on DirectShow as well) for cpp with opencv [check the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630710/opencv-how-to-get-raw-yuy2-image-from-webcam/25151882#25151882)

Answer (score 0):

The Expression Encoder SDK may do what you need depending on exactly what you need to do with the video.

Answer (score 0):

try Emgu or OpenCvCSharp - both OpenCv wrappers which have capture functionality and will return you a RGB image.